# SharePoint 2013 - Errror "Cannot import hello web part sharepoint 2013"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, wspbuilder

I am new to SharePoint 2013. 
I am using SharePoint 2013 server and vs 2010.

The SharePoint Server 2013 and VS2010 is present on different PC's. I have created a new "Hello" visual web-part in vs 2010 using "WSPBuilder". I have just added a "Hello" text to web-part and I try to upload the web-part to my site and getting the error as below:

> "Cannot import hello web part"

Can any one help to solve this problem.

Comment: What does the ULS log or EventViewer give you of errors?

Comment: Where I can find the ULS log or EventViewerLog. Can you tell me as I am new to sharepoint

Comment: Path to ULS log: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Path to EventViewer: Start menu > Administrative tools > EventViewer

Comment: Thank you. I have check both ULS log and EventViewer. It is not showing any log information. Any help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this wil help. There are some things you have to check:

```
1.If Package has SharePoint Product Version set to 15.0
2.Your project is build on .net 4.5
3.You are not deploying on a different farm
4.You are referencing the right sharepoint 2013 assemblies
```